# How to create barcode in Java

Tags: java

I want to create a barcode in Java. I tried the following code, but barcode created and displayed an error on console:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

What I tried so far I attached below

```
 public String barcode()
    {
        String bar = "";
        String alphs ="ABCDFEJKZCVBNMFTYWQRTNMGFDS";
        
        char al[] = alphs.toCharArray();
        
        int n1 =(int)((Math.random()*100)%26);
        int n2 =(int)((Math.random()*100)%26);
        int n3 =(int)((Math.random()*100)%26);
        int n4 =(int)((Math.random()*100)%10);
        int n5 =(int)((Math.random()*100)%10);
        int n6 =(int)((Math.random()*100)%10);       
        bar = al[n1]+ ""+ al[n2]+""+ al[n3]+"-"+ n4+ ""+ n5+ ""+ n6;  
        return bar;
  
    }
```

Comment: looking good to me and running as well https://ideone.com/SMS2Lo

Comment: ya thankssssssssssssss

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: It is very simple: that exception tells you that you try to parse an empty string. The code you are showing shouldnt return an empty string. So something ELSE most be wrong. In code you arent showing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is correct by 6000000 counts.

`for (int i = 0; i <6000000 ; i++) { String barcode = barcode(); System.out.println(barcode); }`
Please check your environment.